# How to test a Spring method for adding a file to GridFS with JUnit and Mockito?

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit4, gridfs, hexagonal-architecture

@Override
public String addMaquette(MultipartFile maquette, String keySousRubrique, String projectId, String titrePage) throws IOException {

```
    DBObject metadata = new BasicDBObject();
    metadata.put("fileSize", maquette.getSize());
    metadata.put("keySousRubrique",keySousRubrique);
    metadata.put("projectId",projectId);
    metadata.put("titrePage",titrePage);

    Object fileID = template.store(maquette.getInputStream(), maquette.getOriginalFilename(), maquette.getContentType(), metadata);

    return fileID.toString();
}
```

I'm new to unit testing with JUnit and Mockito, and I'm not sure of the best way to test this method. Can you provide me with some guidance or examples of unit tests for this method?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Which behavior of your unit do you want to test? Why is Spring relevant for your question?